# Problem With interfacing of 16 Servo MG996R with Arduino Uno

Tags: arduino-uno, servo, battery

I am using 16 MG996R servo motor with PCA9685 servo driver with Arduino Uno, but the motors are not working properly. What is the best power supply/battery for my project as it worked well earlier but is not working right now.

Comment: which part of your question is about the Arduino?

Comment: I am interfacing PCA using Arduino Uno

Comment: You need a power supply that is rated for the same voltage as your servos, and can provide *at least* the total amount of current for all the servos combined.

Comment: Same case here.... Have you solved the problem yet?
Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

I use a 2s battery setup. Specifically Tenergy 18650 Lion 2600mah 7.4v. These are PCB protected lithium battery packs.

I use 3 of them in parallel 7.4v  7800mah.

BTW. I also use a UBEC rated at 7 amps to bring the voltage down to 6v.